# Simple addition and displaying answer on another form - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I wish to simply add the figures entered into a textbox on one form and display the answer on another form. i.e. the customersubmit form.

here is the code i have so far.

```
    Dim x, y As Integer
    x = CInt(TextBox14.Text)

    y = CInt(TextBox10.Text)

    CustomerSubmit.TextBox1 = x + y
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

CustomerSubmit.TextBox1.text = x + y